# Vue SSR (Server Side Rendering) with parcel?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, server-side-rendering, parceljs

I am wondering whether anyone can point me to resources or examples on how to set up parcel for vue SSR (Server Side Rendering).

Or is Vue SSR not possible with parcel?

Comment: Gatsby.js is SSR React + Webpack. Not what you're looking for obviously, but it's setup and is fantastic.

Comment: I would look to see if Parcel does any kind of Server Side Rendering. They I would see if that can apply to Vue.

Comment: Maybe you can try to use Nuxt.js with your project ? Under this link you can read a lot about this problem maybe you will find sth usefull: https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/3464
```"If you meant that Parcel should try and support it by itself(e.g via @parcel/react-ssr), i don't really think it's Parcel's job to support them."```

Answer (score -2):

Should be as simple as installing the various libraries needed:

```
# Yarn
$ yarn add parcel-bundler parcel-plugin-vue @vue/component-compiler-utils babel-preset-env -D

# NPM
$ npm install parcel-bundler parcel-plugin-vue @vue/component-compiler-utils babel-preset-env --save-dev
```

Now you can run `npx parcel` and you'll be ready to go.

For more detail see: https://alligator.io/vuejs/vue-parceljs/

Comment: I've [tried](https://github.com/chriscalo/vue-ssr/tree/alligator.io-tutorial) the linked tutorial and it doesn't address SSR.

Comment: @cdstamper Maybe you can help me. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59524595/how-can-i-implement-server-side-rendering-ssr-on-the-vuetify-project-that-is-1