# How can I implement server side rendering (ssr) on the vuetify project that is 100% complete?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-component, vuetify.js, server-side-rendering

I had install my project vuetify with this reference : https://vuetifyjs.com/en/

My project has been 100% complete. Now I want to implement SSR for Search Engine Optimization (SEO)

I search on google and I find there exist 3 option to implement SSR to vuetify project

1. https://ssr.vuejs.org/
2. https://github.com/vuetifyjs/webpack-ssr
3. https://nuxtjs.org/

If I using option 2 or option 3, it seems I must to change my template. Maybe I should rewrite my code on the template. Because my template using vuetify template. I don't know if I choose option 1. Whether it also has to change my template or not. I must to try it first

What I want to ask is if in my position I have completed the 100% vuetify project, which is the best choice I should choose for SSR implementation?

Do I have to rewrite my code or is there another way to implement it?

Comment: You can have SEO without server side rendering.  Is there any specific reason you can't do static site generation, aka pre-rendering?

Comment: @HMilbradt Really? It seems pre-rendering also needs to change my template

Comment: You might have some luck with this Webpack plugin: https://github.com/chrisvfritz/prerender-spa-plugin.  I have no experience with it, but I have seen plenty of projects using this, and it shouldn't require restructuring your project.

Comment: @HMilbradt Really? I will try that first. Hopefully that doesn't change much of my code. Do you have a sample website that uses pre-rendering? I want to confirm whether it really supports SEO or not

Comment: Unfortunately i don't have one that I can share.  You could try downloading this example and following the instructions for building and serving from the reeadme: https://github.com/chrisvfritz/prerender-spa-plugin/tree/master/examples/vue2-webpack-router.  You should then be able to check the HTML files to see that content and meta tags are rendering correctly

Comment: @HMilbradt Great. Thanks a lot. I will try it first